# netlify.toml and _redirects file not working gives page not found angular project

Tags: angular, angularjs, deployment, netlify

When deploying angular project on netlify not convert from https://netlify to a new domain, netlify.toml and _redirects not working as expected and gives an error with 404 page not found

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include the _redirects file in your angular.json assets array so that Angular will include a copy of the file when building your project:

```
"assets": [
  "src/_redirects"
]
```

See more details here: https://docs.netlify.com/integrations/frameworks/angular/

Comment: Also check if your outputPath of the angular.json matches with the publish directory (build settings at netlify)